# comparison condition in case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, comparison, case

I want to have a comparison in case statement in sql statement

```
  SUM(CASE 
    WHEN bt.idBillingStatus = 2  and o.idOperator = 5 and cs.idClub=1
    THEN (price * revenueShareAmountLocal * o.mfactor *0.08)
```

and  second one is

```
SUM(CASE 
    WHEN bt.idBillingStatus = 2  and o.idOperator = 5 and cs.idClub=2
    THEN (price * revenueShareAmountLocal * o.mfactor *0.04)
```

I want make a comparison that `if bt.idBillingStatus = 2  and o.idOperator = 5 and cs.idClub=2 > bt.idBillingStatus = 2  and o.idOperator = 5 and cs.idClub=1`
then `(price * revenueShareAmountLocal * o.mfactor *0.01)`

Else
`if bt.idBillingStatus = 2  and o.idOperator = 5 and cs.idClub=2 < bt.idBillingStatus = 2  and o.idOperator = 5 and cs.idClub=1`
then `(price * revenueShareAmountLocal * o.mfactor *0.08)`

In simple words, I need to put a comparison in the case statement that if one is greater than another then sum this else sum something else.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Your sample code after "I want to make a comparison" makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not included your data or table structures the help we can provide here is limited, though it sounds like you need one of the following:

```
SUM(CASE 
      WHEN bt.idBillingStatus = 2  and o.idOperator = 5 and cs.idClub=1
        THEN (price * revenueShareAmountLocal * o.mfactor *0.08)

      WHEN bt.idBillingStatus = 2  and o.idOperator = 5 and cs.idClub=2
        THEN (price * revenueShareAmountLocal * o.mfactor *0.04)

      ELSE 0
    END
   )
```

or the sightly more verbose option, which would suggest bad query design on your part that should be looked into:

```
CASE
  WHEN SUM(CASE 
             WHEN bt.idBillingStatus = 2  and o.idOperator = 5 and cs.idClub=2
               THEN (price * revenueShareAmountLocal * o.mfactor *0.04)

             ELSE 0
           END
          )
       > SUM(CASE 
             WHEN bt.idBillingStatus = 2  and o.idOperator = 5 and cs.idClub=1
               THEN (price * revenueShareAmountLocal * o.mfactor *0.08)

             ELSE 0
           END
          )
  THEN SUM(CASE 
             WHEN bt.idBillingStatus = 2  and o.idOperator = 5 and cs.idClub=2
               THEN (price * revenueShareAmountLocal * o.mfactor *0.04)

             ELSE 0
           END
          )

   ELSE SUM(CASE 
             WHEN bt.idBillingStatus = 2  and o.idOperator = 5 and cs.idClub=1
               THEN (price * revenueShareAmountLocal * o.mfactor *0.08)

             ELSE 0
           END
          )
END
```

Comment: Thanks. Do we really have to use else and end with every nested statement?

Comment: @PythonDev  The `else` is technically optional, though it avoids potentially unhandled execution paths. And yes, the `end` is required.  You will get an invalid syntax error if you don't include it.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the 2 sums in an sub query.
And then compare the results in the outer query. 
Which is probably the most readable method.

Or you could put a case around the sums.

For example:

```
-- Using a single table variable for testing reasons
declare @Test table (groupid int, idBillingStatus int, idOperator int, idClub int, price float, revenueShareAmountLocal float, mfactor int);
insert into @Test (groupid, idBillingStatus, idOperator, idClub, price, revenueShareAmountLocal, mfactor) values
(1000,2,5,1,100,20,2),
(1000,2,5,2,100,20,2),
(2000,2,5,2,100,20,2),
(2000,2,5,1,200,20,2),
(2000,2,5,2,100,20,2);

select groupid, idBillingStatus, idOperator, result1, result2,
(case 
 when result2 > result1 then result2 * 0.01
 else result2 * 0.08
 end) as finalresult2
from (
    select groupid, idBillingStatus, idOperator, 
    SUM(
     case 
     when idClub = 1 and idBillingStatus = 2 and idOperator = 5
     then price * revenueShareAmountLocal * mfactor
     end) as result1,
    SUM(
     case
     when idClub = 2 and idBillingStatus = 2 and idOperator = 5
     then price * revenueShareAmountLocal * mfactor
     end) as result2
    from @Test
    group by groupid, idBillingStatus, idOperator
) q;

-- On in 1 select, comparing the sums
select groupid, idBillingStatus, idOperator, 
CASE 
WHEN SUM(case when idClub = 2 and idBillingStatus = 2 and idOperator = 5 then price * revenueShareAmountLocal * mfactor end) >
     SUM(case when idClub = 1 and idBillingStatus = 2 and idOperator = 5 then price * revenueShareAmountLocal * mfactor end)
THEN SUM(case when idClub = 2 and idBillingStatus = 2 and idOperator = 5 then price * revenueShareAmountLocal * mfactor end) * 0.01
ELSE SUM(case when idClub = 2 and idBillingStatus = 2 and idOperator = 5 then price * revenueShareAmountLocal * mfactor end) * 0.08
END as result          
from @Test
group by groupid, idBillingStatus, idOperator;
```